# Cors is not working in Laravel 6 and vue js 2

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2, cors

I have tried many solutions from stackoverflow and youtube but my problem is not solved.
I think my method to make middleware for cors is correct and maybe I'm making mistake in code. Please check below code.
I'm trying to call outlook calender and trying to login with social media but i got same error

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at**

Code is here.

Cors middleware function in http->middleware->Cors

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',"*")
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods',"PUT,DELETE,POST,GET,OPTIONS")
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization');
}
```

"Added these lines in kernel file under global middleware"

```
 \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

Routes in web.php

```
 Route::get('/outlook-callback', 'IntegrationsController@outlook_callback');
 Route::get('/azure-signin', 'IntegrationsController@signin');
```

MY functions in  IntegrationsController

```
public function signin()
{ 
    //var_dump(config('values.OAUTH_APP_ID'));
    // Initialize the OAuth client
    $oauthClient = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
      'clientId'                => config('values.OAUTH_APP_ID'),
      'clientSecret'            => config('values.OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD'),
      'redirectUri'             => config('values.OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI'),
      'urlAuthorize'            => config('values.OAUTH_AUTHORITY').config('values.OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT'),
      'urlAccessToken'          => config('values.OAUTH_AUTHORITY').config('values.OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT'),
      'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
      'scopes'                  => config('values.OAUTH_SCOPES')
    ]);
    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($oauthClient);
    // echo "</pre>";
    $authUrl = $oauthClient->getAuthorizationUrl();
    //print_r($authUrl);

    // Save client state so we can validate in callback
    session(['oauthState' => $oauthClient->getState()]);

    // Redirect to AAD signin page
    return redirect()->away($authUrl);
     // return response()->json(['status' =>'success','message'=>'auth url','authUrlData'=>$authUrl],200);
}
```

and  callback functions is

```
 public function outlook_callback(Request $request)
{ 
   print_r($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Route::get('/outlook-callback', 'IntegrationsController@outlook_callback')->middleware('Cors');
Route::get('/azure-signin', 'IntegrationsController@signin')->middleware('Cors');
```

Comment: i tried your solutuion but now i am getting this error "Target class [Cors] does not exist."  
i ahve file in http->middleware->Cors and also mentioned in kernel file bellow routeMiddleware as "'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,"

Answer (score 0):

As I tried every possible solution i found but nothing worked for me.
I solved my problem by doing following things.

I did not redirect to other url in laravel controller because by doing this i was giving error as mentioned in Question.

I return that redirct url in response to axios request..and then i used

```
window.location =  response.data.authUrlData // authUrlData is the redirect url.
```

I do not know it is the right way to do it but the only way i get rid of my CORS Error.

So i think to share my answer maybe it will help someone in someway.